# Understanding C Code with typedef and Structures

Tags: c, arrays, struct, typedef

Here are the relevant snippets of the .c file I am trying to make sense of :

Background before you read the snippet :

A thread is listening on a socket, once it gets a packet. It reads the data(which is a name of command), and depending on the data(command) takes an action.

```
#define HANDLER(cmd) {#cmd, cmd} 

handler_t table[] = {
    HANDLER(LOAD),
    HANDLER(STORE),
    HANDLER(REMOVE),
};

typedef struct _handler_t
{
    char cmd[CMD_LEN];
    void (*handler)(int argc, char *argv[], int sockfd);
} handler_t;


for (i = 0; i < sizeof(table) / sizeof(handler_t); i++)
    if (strcmp(cmd, table[i].cmd) == 0)  // where cmd is an array whose content were read from socket
        table[i].handler(argc, argv, sockfd);
```

Why `sizeof(table) / sizeof(handler_t)` ?

Why `table[i].handler(argc, argv, sockfd);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`table` is an array of `handler_t`, `sizeof(table)` is the size of the entire array, `sizeof(handler_t)` is the size of one element. So `sizeof(table) / sizeof(handler_t)` is the number of elements of the array. Another more common way to get it is `sizeof(table) / sizeof(table[0])`.

`handler` is a function pointer, so `table[i].handler(argc, argv, sockfd);` calls the function that the function pointer points.

Comment: When calling the function pointer, what role is #define playing?

Comment: @Myth17 The macro substitution has no special role in the call of function pointer, it's done in preprocessing time, replace the macros with their values(which isn't shown in the question) and then see if it's clear.

Comment: The #define made declaring the table easier.

Comment: HANDLER(LOAD) should be substituted by {#LOAD, LOAD},  I dont understand how it is relevant when initialising an array of type handler_t which is a Structure?

Comment: @Myth17 The #defined macro produces table entries consisting of the name of the command and its handler function, e.g., `{"LOAD", LOAD}`. You're asking about a fairly advanced snippet of code; it would be wise to learn the features of the language it uses -- macros, stringification, sizeof, function pointers, etc. -- before trying to understand this code.

Comment: @Myth17 "HANDLER(LOAD) should be substituted by {#LOAD, LOAD}" -- No, it is replaced with `{"LOAD",LOAD}` -- the stringification of #foo is a preprocessor feature. Study your C reference or tutorial. Not just stringifications but struct initializers.

Comment: "Another more common way" -- and far safer; if `table` were changed to have entries of a different type, this code could calculate the wrong count.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JimBalter. I was not aware of stringification. I am working on a C codebase after a very long time and plan to start brushing on my C concepts very soon.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(table)/sizeof(handler_t)` : `sizeof(table)` is the size of the "table" in bits, so as this table is an array of `handler_t`, `sizeof(table) / sizeof(handler_t)` gives the number of element in this table and thus the maximal value for the index.

`table[i].handler(argc, argv, sockfd)`: This is a call for function and as you can see, handler is a function that takes `argc`, `argv` and `sockfd` as parameters.

Comment: When calling the function pointer, what role is #define playing?

Comment: I think `sizeof(table) is bytes, not bits.

Answer (score 0):

```
sizeof(table) / sizeof(handler_t) // gives number of elements in the array 'table'
```